# In what cases doesn't Wordpress update automatically?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wonder in which cases Wordpress does not update automatically. Of course, except when the user / programmer automatically disables updates in the wp-config file. Other cases?

Comment: it's a permissions things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the following 4 things are being updated automatically

1. Core Updates
2. Plugin Updates
3. Theme Updates
4. Translation file updates

Core updates have the following branches:

1. Bleeding Edge
2. Minor/Security Updates
3. Major Updates

By default only Minor Core Updates are being updated automatically where the others are not.
You can read more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates)
Of course, if the permissions are not setted correctly, WordPress isn’t able to perform updates in any way.